# Error: org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Seek to current after exception;

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, apache-kafka

i was trying to implement a kafka consumer applcation with spring boot, but i am getting the below error while fetching a record.

```
org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Seek to current after exception; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method 'public void com.iesd.devops.kafkaconsumer.service.ConsumerService.consumeTestExecutionEvents(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord<java.lang.String, com.iesd.devops.kafkaconsumer.entity.TestExecutionEvent>)' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSource' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.datasource-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties': Could not bind properties to 'DataSourceProperties' : prefix=spring.datasource, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@145f66e3 has not been refreshed yet; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSource' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.datasource-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties': Could not bind properties to 'DataSourceProperties' : prefix=spring.datasource, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@145f66e3 has not been refreshed yet
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekUtils.seekOrRecover(SeekUtils.java:157) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.handle(SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.java:103) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeErrorHandler(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1867) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1773) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1701) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1599) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1330) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1062) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:970) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.5.0.RELEASE]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method 'public void com.iesd.devops.kafkaconsumer.service.ConsumerService.consumeTestExecutionEvents(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord<java.lang.String, com.iesd.devops.kafkaconsumer.entity.TestExecutionEvent>)' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSource' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.datasource-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties': Could not bind properties to 'DataSourceProperties' : prefix=spring.datasource, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@145f66e3 has not been refreshed yet; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSource' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.datasource-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties': Could not bind properties to 'DataSourceProperties' : prefix=spring.datasource, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@145f66e3 has not been refreshed yet
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.decorateException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1879) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.5.0.RELEASE]
        ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSource' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.datasource-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties': Could not bind properties to 'DataSourceProperties' : prefix=spring.datasource, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@145f66e3 has not been refreshed yet
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:409) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:623) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:378) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.detectPersistenceExceptionTranslators(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:168) ~[spring-tx-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:150) ~[spring-tx-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:149) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy90.findQualityGatePayloadBySubmissionId(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at com.iesd.devops.kafkaconsumer.service.ConsumerService.postTestDetailsToDatabase(ConsumerService.java:103) ~[classes!/:na]
        at com.iesd.devops.kafkaconsumer.service.ConsumerService.consumeTestExecutionEvents(ConsumerService.java:75) ~[classes!/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:171) ~[spring-messaging-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:120) ~[spring-messaging-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:48) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:334) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:86) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:51) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1834) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1817) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1760) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.5.0.RELEASE]
        ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSource' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.datasource-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties': Could not bind properties to 'DataSourceProperties' : prefix=spring.datasource, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@145f66e3 has not been refreshed yet
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:539) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1306) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        ... 52 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.datasource-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties': Could not bind properties to 'DataSourceProperties' : prefix=spring.datasource, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@145f66e3 has not been refreshed yet
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.bind(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:92) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:78) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:416) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1788) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1306) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        ... 66 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@145f66e3 has not been refreshed yet
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.assertBeanFactoryActive(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1095) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1113) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.BoundConfigurationProperties.get(BoundConfigurationProperties.java:78) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBinder.getHandler(ConfigurationPropertiesBinder.java:127) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBinder.getBindHandler(ConfigurationPropertiesBinder.java:109) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBinder.bind(ConfigurationPropertiesBinder.java:89) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.bind(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:89) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE]
        ... 80 common frames omitted
```

Listener:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "test_execution",containerFactory = "testListenerContainerFactory")
public void consumeTestExecutionEvents(ConsumerRecord<String, TestExecutionEvent> consumerRecord) {
    LOGGER.info("received payload='{}'", consumerRecord.value());
    postTestDetailsToDatabase(consumerRecord.value());
    latch.countDown();
}
public void postTestDetailsToDatabase(TestExecutionEvent event) {
    System.out.println(event.getKey());
    QualityGatePayload qualityGatePayload = payloadRepository.findQualityGatePayloadBySubmissionId(event.getKey());
    System.out.println(qualityGatePayload);
    event.getPayload().setQualityGatePayload(qualityGatePayload);
    event.setPayload(processResultXmlFile(event.getPayload()));
    testSuiteDetailsRepository.save(event.getPayload());
    testEventRepository.save(event);
}

public TestSuiteDetails processResultXmlFile(TestSuiteDetails testSuiteDetails) {
    String resultXmlPath = testSuiteDetails.getResultFile();
    resultXmlPath = resultXmlPath.replace(resultXmlPath.substring(0,resultXmlPath.indexOf("/wa/")+3),"/ies/iesd_data3_nb/iesdwa/qualitygates/wa");
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new XmlMapper();
    TestSuite testSuite = null;
    try {
        testSuite = objectMapper.readValue(
                StringUtils.toEncodedString(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(resultXmlPath)), StandardCharsets.UTF_8),
                TestSuite.class);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    testSuiteDetails.setErrors(testSuite.getErrors());
    testSuiteDetails.setFailures(testSuite.getFailures());
    testSuiteDetails.setHostname(testSuite.getHostname());
    testSuiteDetails.setName(testSuite.getName());
    if(testSuite.getErrors() == 0 && testSuite.getFailures() == 0) {
        testSuiteDetails.setResult("PASS");
    } else {
        testSuiteDetails.setResult("FAIL");
    }
    testSuiteDetails.setSkipped(testSuite.getSkipped());
    List<TestCaseDetails> testCaseDetailsList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(TestCase testCase: testSuite.getTestcase()){
        TestCaseDetails testCaseDetails = new TestCaseDetails();
        testCaseDetails.setTestSuite(testSuiteDetails);
        testCaseDetails.setErrorMessage(testCase.getError().getMessage());
        testCaseDetails.setErrorType(testCase.getError().getType());
        testCaseDetails.setFailureMessage(testCase.getFailure().getMessage());
        testCaseDetails.setFailureType(testCase.getFailure().getType());
        testCaseDetails.setName(testCase.getName());
        testCaseDetails.setTime(testCase.getTime());
        testCaseDetailsList.add(testCaseDetails);
    }
    testSuiteDetails.setTestCases(testCaseDetailsList);
    testSuiteDetails.setTests(testSuite.getTests());
    testSuiteDetails.setTimestamp(LocalDateTime.parse(testSuite.getTimestamp()));

    return testSuiteDetails;
}
```

from the stacktrace i can see that it is failing at below line in postTestDetailsToDatabase().

> QualityGatePayload qualityGatePayload = payloadRepository.findQualityGatePayloadBySubmissionId(event.getKey());

This is working in intellij and command line and not in server machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I was able to solve this. This is because of a tomacat server running on the same machine with port 8080. And spring boot was not able to change the default port 8080, if another application is using it. After setting the different port, its working fine.

Comment: Hi Vazid! I was stuck with the same error, but tomcat is running on port 8100. Also haven't this error on IDE and console. What did did you mean, that "spring boot was not able to change it"? Why do you think that problem was with port of tomcat?

Comment: In my case, i have started the spring boot application on 8080 and forgot kill it. And again i started the same application which resulted in above error. After killing the first application, i was able to resolve the error.

Comment: After trying different approaches to resolve problem for few hours, error has been defeated. Yes, your answer was right. Problem was with different version running on the same machine. Waisted so much time, because after killing app on port 8100 - "lsof -i :8100" showed me that no app running. But after hours, i tried "ps aux | grep "java"", just for check, and it showed me other versions running (it was surprise for me). After killing these versions - all works fine.